# Separate CodeIgniter public folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've been trying to change my CodeIgniter file structure to make it safer and cleaner but I can't get it to work. I want to separate the application/system and the public files that are going to be visible to users.

```
- application
- system
- public
```

It works but I have to enter

> example.com/public/index.php or example.com/public/controller

I want to be able to just type the base URL like example.com/controller.

How can I do it?

Comment: `public` would simply be the `www` root or `public_html` folder.  Then `system` and `application` are installed outside of the `www` root.

Comment: I'm using a shared hosting. The path to my CI directory is /var/www/myfolder/. I don't know if I really should do this but I read that it's not safe to not separate the folders.

Comment: Where did you read that?!  The official documentation specifically states that you *should* put the `application` and `system` folders **above** of the `www` root.  This virtually guarantees that the public will never see them, even if the `.htaccess` files fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For CodeIgniter 3.x, the correct way to approach this (at this point in 2018 and after) is as follows:

- Make a `public` folder in your root folder
- **MOVE** your index.php file into this folder (to prevent ambiguity)
- inside the moved index.php file, change the following:

  ## change `$system_path` to `../system`

  ## change `$application_folder` to `../application`

Now, we need an `.htaccess` file, but CI 3.x doesn't have a .htaccess file by default, soo.. how about stealing it from CI 4.x which has it by default?  You can find it here:

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/public/.htaccess

I recommend you NOT include the line `SetEnv CI_ENVIRONMENT development` - instead, define this in your apache or NGinx .conf file so the .htaccess file can work anywhere.

Finally, you'll meed to update your .conf file so that `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is set to the subfolder named public (or whatever you chose to name it).  Then restart Apache/Nginx.

That should give you the same results, and be much more secure.

-- UPDATE --
I found that I had problems with the `.htaccess` file from CI 4, however suspect it's my system that's the problem.  This simple version did work however:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

[As per the CodeIgniter Installation Instructions](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html#installation-instructions)...

```
/var/application/
/var/system/
/var/www/index.php
```

> For the best security, both the **system and any application folders should be placed above web root** so that they are not directly accessible via a browser. By default, `.htaccess` files are included in each folder to help prevent direct access, but **it is best** to remove them from public access entirely in case the web server configuration changes or doesn’t abide by the .htaccess.