# location link assets in Codeigniter HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

i have a problem regarding linking to my css,js,images etc. using codeigniter HMVC wiredesignz :https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src/codeigniter-3.x/

i've already configured `base_url` : localhost/my_app/

i got a problem in using this : `<link href="<?=base_url()?>third_party/theme/css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Here is my folder structure

```
-Root
--application
---third_party
----MX
----theme
```

Comment: here is reference link i hope it will help you.
https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-third-party-libraries-folder/

Comment: why cant open this ? @PHPGeek

Comment: you should do yourself a favour and separate public assets from your php containing folders - it leads to a total mess and may create some security issues... - Oliver Williams gave in his post an excellent answer to that - take a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/49341042/3436643